# VBA: What to reference for "htmlfile"?

Tags: html, vba, dom

I found the lines

```
Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
```

and want to use them in my code. Only I like intellisense and option explicit, so I quickly modified the first one to

```
'needs tools>references>microsoft xml, v5.0
Dim xmlHttp As MSXML2.xmlHttp: Set xmlHttp = New MSXML2.xmlHttp
```

My question is: how do i do the same thing for the second line? What do I need to reference to be able to write

```
dim html as htmlfile
```

?

Comment: Create the object, then go into debug mode and see in the watch window what the type is?

Comment: I actually assumed that the type had to be called 'htmlfile'. So your comment would eventually have led me to Santosh's answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just be careful with this one, HTMLFile behaves differently when late bound vs early bound. When bound early methods such as GetElementsbyClass name are available, not so when bound late

Comment: good thing it cleared this up first then. my GetElementsByClassName is already up and running, would have run into trouble there if i hadnt insisted here.

Comment: Yeah, it's a pain when using it in different environments, the features you can use depend on the version of internet explorer installed on the machine. For example, you cannot use GetElementsByClassName unless the user has IE9+ installed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to Tools > Reference > Search for  **Microsoft HTML Object Library** > tick the checkbox > OK

Now you can define html document element using early binding like below

`Dim html As HTMLDocument`

Using late binding you can use below which creates html document element.

`Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")`

[image]

Comment: I did not know that CreateObject("name") can create an object of a type NOT called 'name'.

Comment: I've faced with early bound `HTMLDocument` weird behavior: I try to use `.write` method, and it says _"Compile error: Function or interface marked as restricted, or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic"_, although VBA has the method in autocompletion list. Setting `.body.innerHTML` property helps. Also there is no such problems with late bound `CreateObject("htmlfile")`. Excel 2007 SP3, Win7 HB SP1 x64.