# VBScript GetElementsByClassName not supported?

Tags: vba, vbscript, vb6

I am trying to convert some of my working VBA code to VBScript, but keep getting errors in VBScript when trying to use the getElementsByClassName method. Here's the full code:

```
option explicit

Dim XMLPage, html

Set XMLPage = WScript.CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set html= CreateObject("HTMLFile")

XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.hltv.org/stats/matches/mapstatsid/48745/immortals-vs-dignitas", False
Wscript.Sleep 50
XMLPage.send
Wscript.Sleep 50
If XMLPage.Status <> 200 Then MsgBox XMLPage.statusText

html.Open
html.write XMLPage.responseText
html.Close

'msgbox html.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).innertext'WORKS
msgbox html.getElementsByClassName("match-info-box-con")(0).innertext'DOESNT WORK
```

The last line of code is where the following error occurs:
[image]

If I comment that out and run it to search for a tag name instead (code on the line above) - it works fine no problem.

I suspect it has something to do with how the variable `html` is declared, as from what I understand. `getElementsByClassName` comes from `IHTMLElement6` - but I am unsure on how to get this to work in VBScript.

Comment: `comes from IHTMLElement6` - also from [IHTMLDocument7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff975572(v=vs.85).aspx). [Should work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20495137/11683) on Vista+. You can also try it on `html.body`.

Comment: Thanks, could you please help me by advising how I would apply this to the above code? As this is in VBScript, I have to make all declarations within the code as I can't select references same as what I could in VBA.

Comment: `html.body.getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and got the same error - only in this case it said: doesn't support 'body.getElementsByClassName'. If you have any more ideas on how this could be solved - would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that I am using IE11? After reading this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn384057(v=vs.85).aspx) maybe it's some sort of 'support issue'?

Comment: You have a vbs file. It has nothing to do with IE.

Comment: MSHTML behaves differently depending on how it was instantiated - it exposes different interfaces depending on whether or not its early or late bound (its heavily reliant on IDispatch). You are late binding and no interface exposing `getElementsByClassName` is available. You can loop over `document.all()` and look at each `item.className`.

Comment: Thank you so much, looping through the doc worked perfectly. If you could please copy/paste this as an answer - I will mark it as complete for others reference. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSHTML behaves differently depending on how it was instantiated - it exposes different interfaces depending on whether or not its early or late bound (its heavily reliant on `IDispatch`).

You are late binding and no interface exposing `getElementsByClassName` is available.

You can loop over `document.all()` and look at each `item.className`.

Comment: Isn't there a way to specify the desired version of MSXML when late binding?

Answer (score 0):

I used similar code to retrieve data from a POST request.
getElementsByClassName worked only if preceded with another command, like "msgbox 1" or anything to halt the script for a fraction of a second.
Then I tried Wscript.Sleep 200, decreasing it to the smallest possible number, and it still worked.

```
Wscript.Sleep 1 ' This line got it working.
msgbox html.getElementsByClassName("match-info-box-con")(0).innertext'
```

Comment: It would appear that your problem was that you did not let the document time to load which happens in the background. This has nothing to do with the OP's problem.

Comment: Actually, without that 1 milisecond, the error was the same. I have no idea why 1 milisecond is enough, but is proof that getElementsByClassName is indeed supported. No need for another way initialize the html object.

Answer (score 0):

I took some time to elaborate a working example.
Thanks to GSerg for pointing out the load delay. That is accurate.
Had to tweak the code a little to get it working though.
Based on the previous comments, maybe the behaviour of MSHTML depends on the code being parsed. Hence the aditional meta tag below.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Dim htmldoc: Set htmldoc = CreateObject("htmlfile") 
'    
URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44853941/vbscript-getelementsbyclassname-not-supported"
'   sEnv = ""
'    
objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
'    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
objHTTP.send ' (sEnv)
ttext = objHTTP.responsetext

ttext = "<meta http-equiv=""X-UA-Compatible"" content=""IE=EDGE,chrome=1"" />" & vbnewline & ttext 

htmldoc.write ttext
htmldoc.close
htmldoc.designMode = "on"   ' Refer to https://developpaper.com/method-of-parsing-html-documents-by-vbs-htmlfile/

WScript.ConnectObject htmldoc, "htmldoc_"

Sub htmldoc_onreadystatechange()
  If htmldoc.readyState = "interactive" Then
      ttext = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("fs-headline1").Item(0).innerText
      msgbox ttext
      Wscript.quit
  End If
End Sub

'-----------------
Wscript.Sleep 10000  ' Random timeout
msgbox "Timeout!"
```