# File System Object late binding

Tags: vba, excel, filesystemobject

I have problem with `File System Object` late binding. This is my code:

```
Dim WordA As Object 'aplikacja programu Word
Dim PlikW As Object 'plik Worda
Dim Nazwa As Object 'obszar Worda ze zdefiniowaną nazwą
Dim Zakres As Range 'zakres danych używany do wiadomości
Dim NrRaportu As Integer 'Numer tworzonego raportu
Dim Katalog As String 'pełna nazwa katalogu, w którym zapisywane są wiadomości
Const Raport_szablon = "Raport_szablon.docx" 'zazwa pliku z szablonem
Dim fso As Object 'Objekt FileSystemObject

'1. Wczytanie danych
Set Zakres = Range("R2:Z" & Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row)
Katalog = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Raporty"
Set fso = CreateObject("FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(Katalog) Then _
    fso.CreateFolder (Katalog)
```

and I get a message that

> "ActiceX component can't create object"

.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use FileSystemObject in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3233203/11683)

Comment: You need `Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` rather than simply `Set fso = CreateObject("FileSystemObject")`

Comment: You are right, many thanks! Do you happen to know why using late binding I can't save files in PDF format? Using early binding it works well. Here's my code: PlikW..ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=Katalog & "\" & Marka & ".pdf", ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False

Comment: Put `Option Explicit` on top [to learn why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14122422/11683).

Comment: Late vs. early binding should have zero implications as to the functionality of the created objects.

Comment: @JohnColeman [Apparently not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44862518/11683) (although it's not the culprit here).

Comment: i received a message: Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: @GSerg Interesting. Learn something new every day.

Comment: Its needed also to register the underlaying dll as a reference in the reference manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need also to use the reference manger and add the dll / ocx to the project. c:\windows\system32\wshom.ocx if i remember right