# VBA Web Scraping on Medium Integrity IE - Run-time Error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: vba

I'd like to scrape an intranet application, and I'd like to select an item from a drop-down menu.

I've read that I have to open up a medium integrity level instance of Internet Explorer to access intranet sites.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
'Open up medium IL IE
Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")

With appIE
    .Navigate2 "https://gbs.nam.nsroot.net/GBS/cis.jsp"
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

Set Title = appIE.document.getElementsByClassName(" oraDefault ")(1)
Title.Value = "2001"
```

However, I get the run-time error when the code tries to execute the getElementsByClassName, and I'm not entirely sure what is happening or how this works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript GetElementsByClassName not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44853941/11683)

Comment: I can use  appIE.document.querySelectorAll(".oraDefault").item(1) in my test case.