# getElementsByClassName in VBA produces Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Disclosure: I'm an office clerk trying to automate the most boring copy-paste part of my job and have 0 knowledge of VBA or HTML. Thank you for your patience with me.

I was able to successfully parse data from intranet page, that I require, by using GetElementByID, however, this particular piece of information doesn't have ID.

I tried getting it using GetElementsByClassName, but it produced error above and I can't figure out why. It seems to work for other people, not for me.

This is my code.

```
Sub ExtractFromEndeca()
 Dim ie As InternetExplorer
 Dim html As IHTMLDocument
 Dim DescData As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
 Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 ie.Visible = False
 ie.Navigate Range("h3")
 While ie.Busy
     DoEvents
     Wend
     While ie.ReadyState < 4
     DoEvents
     Wend
     Set doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
     Set doc = ie.document
     Set DescData = doc.getElementsByClassName("propertyList")
     Set Data = doc.getElementById("findSimilarOptions2")
     Sheet3.Cells(1, 1) = Data.innerText
     Sheet3.Cells(100, 1) = DescData.innerText
     ie.Quit
     Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

This is a fragment of HTML from intranet page, that I require.

```
<table class="propertyList" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <th width="60px">&nbsp;</th>
    <th align="left" colspan=1 width="130px" nowrap>Item Information</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>

</thead>


    <tr>
    <td rowspan=6 valign=top width="60px"><a href="Wierd looking link"><img border=0 alt="Locate Item" src="Wierd Gif"></a>
    </td>
    <td valign=top nowrap><b>Property(1)</b></td>
    <td>Value(1)</td>


    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap><b>Property(2)</b></td>
        <td>Value(2)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap><b>Property(3)</b></td>
        <td>Value(3)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap><b>Property(4)</b></td>
        <td>Property(4)</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap><b>Property(5)</b></td>
        <td>Value(5)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td nowrap><b>Property(6)</b></td>
        <td>Value(6)</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBScript GetElementsByClassName not supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44853941/11683)

Comment: I see no elements with an ID of `findSimilarOptions2` in your example.

Comment: @braX That's the one I was able to get actually. So I thought it is not relevant to show it in HTML sample. Now I'm trying to get table with class "propertylist". However, I thought there is a conflict between those lines, maybe? So I'm showing it in VBA code.

Comment: *getElement**s**ByClassName()* creates a node collection. The elements of the node collection have indexes. The first index is 0. If you want the first element you must write *Set DescData = doc.getElementsByClassName("propertyList")(0)* The method *getElementByID()* doesn't create a node list. So it give no indexes.

Comment: @Zwenn Thanks, that may be the reason, but I'm pretty sure I tried that, however, after rebooting my laptop, it has magically started to work =). Thanks again you for your time and your help.