# Runtime Error 91 for scraping a specific html div tag innertext to spreadsheet using vba

Tags: html, excel, runtime, vba

I'm trying to scrape a particular data point from thousands of different (but similar) webpages. (I need the EBITDA for different companies). See my code below.

See my macro code below.

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
Sub TAM_Click()

Dim ticker As String
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim RowNumber As Integer
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False

RowNumber = 6
ticker = Sheet1.Cells(RowNumber, 3)
ie.navigate "financials.morningstar.com/income-statement/is.html?t=" + 
ticker + "&ops=clear"
Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
Set html = ie.document

Dim ElementList As IHTMLElement
Dim Elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim Element As IHTMLElement

Set ElementList = html.getElementById("data_i90")
Set Elements = ElementList.Children
For Each Element In Elements
    If Element.ID = "Y_6" Then
    Debug.Print Element.innerText
    End If
Next Element
```

I'm getting a run time error 91 Object Variable or With block variable not set

Through trial and error i've determined that the problem is with setting the variables Elements and Element.

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong? Any help/code critique is greatly appreciated.

#### Edit:

I believe the error may be that the HTML  tags nested withing the IHTMLElementCollection cannot be called with the ElementList.Children operation.. at least that's the first line where I'm getting the runtime error 91. I need to inspect the HTML of the webpage to see why i can't do this

Comment: What Excel version are you using? Try replacing `Dim ie As InternetExplorer: Set ie = New InternetExplorer` To `Dim ie As Object: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`

Comment: And if the reference is not set on VBA, remember to [enable IE reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970672.aspx). In  Tools then References. 
`Set createInternetExplorerObject = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`
[Tools> References> Microsoft Internet Controls.](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/8916/automation-or-using-other-applications-libraries#t=201709300007238904349) 
Associated DLL: ieframe.dll. 
Source: Internet Explorer Browser.

Comment: @danieltakeshi thank you for your help. I'm using Excel 2016. I'd already enabled microsoft internet controls and microsoft HTML Object library. are there more references needed?

Comment: to declare HTML, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20495137/7690982) instead of `Dim html As HTMLDocument`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could use that  method.

Comment: I believe the error may be that the HTML <div> tags nested withing the IHTMLElementCollection cannot be called with the ElementList.Children operation.. at least that's the first line where I'm getting the  runtime error 91. I need to inspect the HTML of the webpage to see why i can't do this.